# Enter new variable as argument

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing, implicit-conversion

I want to create a function that takes some chain of characters as an argument, and uses it as a `str` object.

```
def useless_function(argument) :
    print(argument)

useless_function(banana)
--> NameError: name 'banana' is not defined
```

So this is what I did : I created a decorator that turns whatever I enter as argument into a `str` my function can print.

```
def decorator(f) :

    def wrapper(arg_f) :
        str_arg = str(arg)
        f(str_arg)

    return wrapper
```

So now I can decorate useless_function with my decorator, and `useless_function(banana)` will print `'banana'`. And it will work with whatever it enter as an argument of `useless_function`.

My question is : is there a more elegant way or a simpler and faster way to do this automatic transformation into a string that can be used as an argument ?

Comment: The question is quite difficult to understand. Please, add at least an example of the desired behaviour or of the goal you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In fact, my decorator does not work, because as `argument` was unknown to f (not defined), it is also unknown to the wrapper... So the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate because I don't understand what it is that you are looking for or saying.
If you mean: inside a function can you do `input("variable")`? Then the answer is yes. It is just essentially `raw_input()` from python2. The input from your keyboard will always be a `str` if I am not mistaken.

*Update after edited post:*

It is still not any more clear what you are trying to do.
At the end of the function, you do `return *` but I assume you know this.

I am really confused, but have you considered just doing `str(argument)`? As in `takes_argument(str(argument))`

*2nd Update after 2nd edit:*

I think I finally understand what you are trying to do, but I might be wrong.

Now, the problem is that `def useless_function(argument) :` will expect `argument` to be defined as a variable with some value(s). I am not aware of any other way than actually putting `"argument"` to tell python that what you are inserting is a string of characters rather than trying to reference some variable and its value. It is the same case as with `print('something')`, if I were to put `print(something)`, python would try to look up the variable called `something` which you haven't defined.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it became clearer. I am trying to create a function that takes text as an argument. Like what you would give to raw_input) before it turns it into a str.

Comment: Yes, I tried `str(argument)` and it raised a `SyntaxError`... I hope the second edit will be clearer again.